# Enviar do dados MultiSelect do Modal

Tags: html, c#, jquery

Gostaria de uma ajudar com esse código:
Estou enviando informações de uma tabela para o modal e nessa tabela vai ter dados dos grupos separados por virgula e eu gostaria que fosse selecionado no modal em MultiSelect que nem o exemplo de baixa que é usuários. O MultiSelect de baixo funciona perfeitamente mas não sei como fazer nesse primeiro modelo.
Modelo foi retirado desse site http://loudev.com/
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.6" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://loudev.com/css/multi-select.css"/>
  <script src="https://loudev.com/js/jquery.multi-select.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
                      <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                        <table class="table">
                          <thead class="thead-dark">
                            <tr class="text-center">
                              <th class="d-none"></th>
                              <th>Página</th>
                              <th>Cód. Página</th>
                              <th>Tipo</th>
                              <th>Grupos</th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <th scope="row">1</th>
                              <td class="d-none">
                                <input type="radio" id="customRadio" name="customRadio" data-envia-id="1" data-envia-pagina="Nome Exemplo" data-envia-codpagina="Situação Exemplo" data-envia-tipo="Pagina" data-envia-grupo="Suporte, Comercial" data-envia-usuarios="usuario1, usuario2" data-envia-observacao="Observacao Exemplo">
                              </td>
                              <td>Mark</td>
                              <td>Otto</td>
                              <td>@mdo</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <th scope="row">1</th>
                              <td class="d-none">
                                <input type="radio" id="customRadio" name="customRadio" data-envia-id="1" data-envia-pagina="Nome Exemplo" data-envia-codpagina="Situação Exemplo" data-envia-tipo="22" data-envia-grupo="Suporte, Comercial" data-envia-observacao="Observacao Exemplo">
                              </td>
                              <td>Jacob</td>
                              <td>Thornton</td>
                              <td>@fat</td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                      </table>
                      </div>
                      </div>
                      <!-- /Modal para cadastro de contratos -->
                      <div class="modal fade" id="Modal-Editar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">
                          <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                              <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"> Realizar Alterações</h4>
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                              </button>
                            </div>
                            <form method="POST" action="teste.php">
                              <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 form-group has-feedback">
                                    <input type="text" name="pagina" id="RecebPagina" class="form-control has-feedback-left"  placeholder="Nome da Página" required>
                                    <span class="fa fa-check-square-o form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12 form-group has-feedback">
                                    <select id="RecebGrupo" class="custom-select text-center" multiple>
                                      <option></option>
                                      <option value="Suporte">Suporte</option>
                                      <option value="Comercial">Comercial</option>
                                      <option value="Agenda">Agenda</option>
                                      <option value="Financeiro">Financeiro</option>
                                    </select>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group has-feedback">
                                    <select id="RecebUsuarios2" class="custom-select" multiple>
                                      <option></option>
                                      <option value="usuario1">usuario1</option>
                                      <option value="usuario2">usuario2</option>
                                      <option value="usuario3">usuario3</option>
                                      <option value="usuario3">usuario3</option>
                                    </select>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-footer text-center">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name='btnValue' value='btnEdiPermissoes'>Editar</button>
                              </div>
                            </form>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.modal-content').resizable({
      //alsoResize: ".modal-dialog",
      minHeight: 300,
      minWidth: 300
    });
    $('.modal-dialog').draggable();

    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
      $(this).find('.modal-body').css({
        'max-height': '100%'
      });
    });
  </script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.modal-dialog').draggable();

        $(document).ready(function(){ 
          $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
        });
        //Função para marcar o checkbox ao clicar na linha: ondblclick
        $("table tr").on("dblclick", function(){
          $(this).children().children()[0].click();
          $('#Modal-Editar').modal('show');

             $.each($("input[name='customRadio']:checked"), function() {
              VarId = $(this).data('envia-id');
              VarPagina = $(this).data('envia-pagina');
              VarCodpagina = $(this).data('envia-codpagina');
              VarTipo = $(this).data('envia-tipo');
              VarUsuarios = $(this).data('envia-usuarios');
              VarGrupo = $(this).data('envia-grupo');
              VarObservacao = $(this).data('envia-observacao');
              $('#RecebId').val(VarId);
              $('#RecebId2').html(VarId);
              $('#RecebPagina').val(VarPagina);
              $('#RecebCodpagina').val(VarCodpagina);
              $('#RecebTipo').html(VarTipo);
              $('#RecebUsuarios').html(VarUsuarios);
              $('#RecebObservacao').val(VarObservacao);


               $('#RecebGrupo option').each(function(index) {
    var str = VarGrupo;
    var substr = str.split(', ');
    
    for (var i = 0; i < substr.length; i++) {
        if (substr[i] == $(this).val()) {
            //$("option:selected", this).attr();
            $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
            //$(this).attr('selected', true);
            //$(this).addClass('ms-elem-selectable ms-hover ms-selected').show();
            //$(this).addClass('ms-hover').show();
            //$(this).addClass('ms-selected').show();

            //$(this).Attr('hidden');
            //$(this).Attr('id', '-190140734-selection');

        }
    }
});



               $('#RecebUsuarios2 option').each(function(index) {
    var str = VarUsuarios;
    var substr = str.split(', ');
    
    for (var i = 0; i < substr.length; i++) {
        if (substr[i] == $(this).val()) {
            //$("option:selected", this).attr();
            $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
            //$(this).attr('selected', true);
            //$(this).addClass('ms-elem-selectable ms-hover ms-selected').show();
            //$(this).addClass('ms-hover').show();
            //$(this).addClass('ms-selected').show();

            //$(this).Attr('hidden');
            //$(this).Attr('id', '-190140734-selection');

        }
    }
});

            }); 


        });
      </script>
      

    <script type="text/javascript">
    // MultiSelect Cadastro de Grupo
    $('#Selected-GrupoCad').multiSelect();
    // MultiSelect Editar Grupo
$('#RecebGrupo').multiSelect();
</script>
  
</body>
</html>
```